# JQM page id and data-url

Tags: jquery-mobile

What is the relation between page id and data-url attribute. Is there any relation. Is it fine to change the data-url attribute.

My issue is that there is a page to which i pass the params using changePage. I also specify the data-url in changePage. After going to that page, if i manually refresh the page a new page is added since the data-url is different for that page. That is, the data-url becomes same as the page id. Hope that am clear on this. What should i do so that the page is replaced during manual refresh of page.

And, can someone please explain how JQM uses page id and data-url. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Browser's location is updated by the value of `data-url`, which is the page's `id`. When you refresh, it updates browser's location with page `id` as there's no value specified.

Comment: Check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/EvkDH/show/) I hope it clarifies the idea of `data-url`. Notice the browser's url having custom `#` tag which is different than the page `id`. but once you referesh, `data-url` will be replace custom values with page `id`. Code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/EvkDH/).

Comment: Can you please explain this better. 1. I have two separate html pages. Say page A and B, Am passing some parameter from A to B and specifying the data-url as "/test/B?type=123". Am able to retrieve the parameter in page B. When I refresh the data-url changes and it adds a new page with data-url same as the page id. My doubt is: 1) What should i do so that i will replace the page with data-url "/test/B?type=123". 2) How will i get the parameter value type=123 when i refresh the page as it will not be available

Comment: Hmmm..this is a tricky question, especially you're using multi-pages. I'll try to get you an answer soon.

Comment: Well, I dont think its possible to keep transferred parameters on refresh. However, it might work if you retrieve it from `window.location.hash`. I still need to test it. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/EvkDH/show/

Comment: Thanks.Am able to get the parameter from window.location.search. But, the issue is the data-url becomes same as the page id. So, when i refresh and then go to the page again there are two pages with the same id in the doc tree, But the data-urls are different. Based on what is the page replaced by JQM. I tried even setting the data-url to be same for both the pages. But, there are two pages created in DOM. What could be the issue here. Hope am clear.

Comment: Once you refresh, browser removes previous visited pages and loads the ones within the current `.html` file. Using same ID for pages would make things complicated, better using unique ID's

Comment: Am using unique id's only.

Comment: In this case, you need to force reload `reloadPage` with `changePage` in order to remove previous pages.

Comment: but, how can i do this during manual refresh of page.

Comment: Hmmm..it's not possible on refresh. But there might be a solution by dynamically injecting pages and removing previous/visited ones. This means that all pages are dynamically created and aren't static.

Comment: Can someone provide me a concrete answer for the above question. Looks like, that am not clear with my question. Or, it is difficult to do some things in JQM. Pls help.

Comment: @user694688 Is there any reason for which you need the `dataUrl` attribute? Without it the parameters will be passed and on refresh the `data-url` will remain the same (page id).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data-url` attribute is used to track the origin of the page element. If it is not explicitly set, the pages embedded within the main application document all have their `data-url` attribute equal to the page `id`. The only exception to this is the first-page in the document. When you're requesting a page, then jQuery Mobile firstly tries to locate a page with a matching `data-url` in DOM. If it does not find a such page then it performs an Ajax request and loads the new page in DOM.

You can solve the issue using one of the below 3 ways:

Use the below code to remove the second page from DOM when you're moving to another page.

```
$(document).on('pagehide', '#second-page', function(event, ui){
    $(event.target).remove();
});
```

This way when you're moving to the first page, the second page will be removed from DOM and your issue will be solved.

**OR**:

Use:

```
$.mobile.changePage('car-details.html', {
    data: {
        id: this.id
    }
});
```

without using the `dataUrl` setting.

This creates a URL: ../car-details.html?id=my_val

On refresh the URL remains the same so you can still get the parameters and the `data-url` is the same as the page id.

**OR**

Before `changePage()` check whether a page with `data-url` equal to the second page's id exists in DOM and remove it manually.

```
if ($("#second-page-id").length > 0 && $("#second-page-id").attr("data-url") === 'second-page-id' ) {
    console.log('remove from DOM');
    $("#second-page-id").remove();
}
```

Comment: When i use the second method specified above, the data-url does not remain same. It becomes same as the page id.

Comment: Also, i have one more doubt. I have a page with data-URL: /car-details.html?id=my_val. I have the same page with different parameter value for id. If the match is going to be based on data-URL, how is the page getting replaced even if the parameter value is different.

Comment: @user694688 Yes, using the second solution, the `data-url` is equal to the page id. Why do you need to have different `data-url`?

Comment: Because, if i go to the same page again, say from a menu, the data-url will be "/car-details.html?id=my_va". But, on manual refresh the data-url will be same as page id, say "cardetails". Because of this, there will be two pages with the same page id, but different data-url's. Ideally, the page should be replaced, because it is the same page.

Comment: @user694688 But using the second solution you don't have different `data-url` attributes. So the same page is replaced. My question is: why do you pass `data-url` on the `changePage` settings?

Comment: @user694688 I've added a third solution as well.

Comment: Am not passing data-url on changePage. Am passing only the data attribute as you have given. From your solutions, i completely understand that we have to remove the page and the first solution works fine. But, as you have mentioned, the second solution is not creating the page with the same data-url, during manual refresh. Hope am clear.

Comment: Just to make it clear: using the second solution, the `data-url` is the same on the page refresh and when you navigate to this page from the first page. So you don't have a page with same id but different `data-url` in DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Am giving the bounty to you for the first solution, which works.